# curl to python scripting issue

Tags: python-3.x, curl, pycurl

i'm trying to convert my curl to a python code, unfortunately without any success.
can anyone help me with this one, please?

```
curl -k -X "POST" "https://192.168.16.220:9000/api/views/search/messages" \
     -H 'X-Requested-By: superman' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -H 'Accept: text/csv' \
     -u 'admin:admin' \
     -d $'{
  "streams": [
    "62948e1fcd664d57cccfa29c"
  ],
  "query_string": {
    "type": "elasticsearch",
    "query_string": "source"
  },
  "timerange": {
    "type": "relative",
    "range": 30
  }
}'
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Comment: ok, we can close it. thanks for the help with the code conversion, wish you a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, also I suggest using [this](https://curlconverter.com/) handy site in the future

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'X-Requested-By': 'superman',
    # Already added when you pass json= but not when you pass data=
    # 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'text/csv',
}

json_data = {
    'streams': [
        '62948e1fcd664d57cccfa29c',
    ],
    'query_string': {
        'type': 'elasticsearch',
        'query_string': 'source',
    },
    'timerange': {
        'type': 'relative',
        'range': 30,
    },
}

response = requests.post('https://192.168.16.220:9000/api/views/search/messages', headers=headers, json=json_data, verify=False, auth=('admin', 'admin'))

# Note: json_data will not be serialized by requests
# exactly as it was in the original request.
#data = '{\n  "streams": [\n    "62948e1fcd664d57cccfa29c"\n  ],\n  "query_string": {\n    "type": "elasticsearch",\n    "query_string": "source"\n  },\n  "timerange": {\n    "type": "relative",\n    "range": 30\n  }\n}'
#response = requests.post('https://192.168.16.220:9000/api/views/search/messages', headers=headers, data=data, verify=False, auth=('admin', 'admin'))
```

get the data from the api like this for json data

```py
json_data = response.json()
```

or get the data from the api like this for text data

```py
json_data = response.text
```

Comment: now the only issue is that i can't print the messages i want i just see a 200 response... and i would like to see the messages from the database...
```
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: just print the `response` var

Comment: i did, but it's weird that i don't see anything except 
<Response [200]>

Comment: that means it worked. [read this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_response.asp)

Comment: I've updated my answer for you

Comment: my code looks like what you've posted above but with the last 3 lines
`response = requests.post('https://172.16.16.220:9000/api/views/search/messages', headers=headers, json=json_data, verify=False, auth=('admin', 'admin'))
messages = response.json()
print(messages)`
 ``and i get some errrors now

Comment: here are the errors:
`
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\mariu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
`

Comment: @Marius or try using `.text()`

Comment: see my answer for the edit

Comment: now i have 
`
File "c:/Users/mariu/Documents/python/graylog_reject_ips copy.py", line 26, in <module>
    message = response.text()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
`

Comment: call `response.text` without the `()`